# Implicit auth flow when redirecting to localhost. Is it insecure?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0

I am currently working on a windows app using python. I want the user to be able to authenticate to their Google Drive so my app can access the files. But I don't want to specify the client_secret in the code.

I heard about the implicit auth flow. But since I just want to redirect to localhost, I don't know if this is suitable for my application.

Comment: implicit auth is deprecrated and no longer recommended. You probably want the `authorization_code` flow instead. It can also work without a secret in case you want your client to initiate the flow.